# Correct verb tense for describing a movie

Tags: tense

Let's say someone has asked you to describe a movie you had recently watched.

What tense would you use to describe it, past tense because it already happened, or present tense because it is a fact?

Comment: I think it depends on how the person is describing the movie, in the past or in the present. "I love so many parts of that movie, like when Arnie says 'I'll be back'" vs "Last week when we saw Terminator, I loved when Arnie said, 'Come with me if you want to live.'"

Comment: I loved it when Arnie said; not I loved when, sorry.

Comment: @dispenser Answers should be put in the answer section. Putting answers in comments bypasses the quality control mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You can describe anything as you want to describe it.

**I saw a movie and it was really good.**

**The movie I saw is really good.**

What do you want to say? And probably, this is true in  your native tongue as well.

Answer (score 1):

You really could choose either past or present tense, so long as you are consistent.  Wikipedia says that [historical present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present) is often preferred for "summaries of the narratives (plots) of works of fiction," but there's nothing wrong with relating the movie's plot in the past tense, especially if you're also going to include your own reactions that you had at the time of viewing.

---

Edited to provide examples:

**Using the historic present to describe the plot:**

Here, you're describing the plot as if it's happening now, and using the present tense to show more immediacy and to more easily differentiate past/future events from the point of view of the story.

> Luke Skywalker is an orphan being raised by his aunt and uncle on a desert planet. His parents died when he was a baby so he can't remember them.  Then he finds these two droids!

Note that things that happen in the course of the movie are in the present tense ("he finds these two droids").  Only things that happened in the past of the story from the point of view of the characters are in the past tense ("his parents died").

**Using the simple past to describe the plot and inserting your own reactions:**

> They were in the trash compactor when they heard a weird animal noise. Suddenly Luke was pulled under water! I was so scared that I dropped my popcorn!"

In this case, you're describing *your experience* of seeing the movie, so the whole thing is in the past tense.

Comment: I think you might give us an example. It's all very theoretical.

Comment: Provided the in depth usage between verb tenses here, I now have a basic foundation for which tenses is correct to use. It seems like this is an advanced question coz you guys are not providing me grammar rules from books... clearly the answers here are 'depending' on the person.

Comment: @Lambie, my example is, I would like to describe the movie:the pursuit of hapiness, by summarizing the storyline. Specifically, I'd like to talk about a movie, 'the pursuit of hapiness' by will smith and his son jaden. The storyline is all about how they beat the odds life threw at them... so on and so forth...(notice I've used past tense here) I've given you an example, kindly put your suggestions if you have. Thx.

Comment: I gave you two examples in my answer, one in the past and one in the present. By example, I mean: how are you starting your sentence? There is a plethora of ways to begin describing a movie. Also, please capitalize English proper nouns, especially names of movies and characters. Thanks. Beat the odds can be present or past, there is no way to tell: beat as present or simple past, in fact.

Comment: There really is no "grammar rule from books" other than whichever tense you choose, you should be consistent.  Certainly if you read things like [movie reviews in the newspaper](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/11/30/movies/the-shape-of-water-review-guillermo-del-toro.html?referrer=google_kp), they will almost always use the present tense when relating the plot, so you can certainly follow the same practice if you want.